# Unable to trigger click on UL Li items in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium-java and chrome driver to select elements from UL list.
I am trying to select item "Sirsa" but nothing is happening.
UL List structure is similar to below:

```html
<div class="serachDept" id="names_department"><span class="departmentText">Mumbai</span>
    <ul class="serachDeptOptionList" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
        <li class="serachDeptOptionListElement"><span data-filter-value="Ratia"
                                                    class="srSearchOptionListElementText">Ratia</span></li>
        <li class="serachDeptOptionListElement"><span data-filter-value="Sirsa"
                                                      class="srSearchOptionListElementText">Sirsa</span></li>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I selected the elements using java code :

```
 WebElement namesList = Hooks.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='names_department']//ul"));
    List<WebElement> options = namesList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    for (WebElement option : options) {
        option.findElement(By.tagName("Span")).click();  // throws exception
    }
    options.get(2).click();//throws exception
```

Exception :

```
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c..., userDataDir: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\T...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: l}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 71.0.3578.98, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: f68d79a1f74f3dc99c15d8a5f3104789
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
  at com.sg.game.steps_def.CareerMenuItemCheck.dropdown_Weblist_is_enabled_and_Clickable(CareerMenuItemCheck.java:253)
```

Could someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: You have chopped off the much needed exception details. IMO,this error stack trace isn't from the code block you are suspecting.

Comment: @MosheSlavin Please avoid using the `<blockquote>` markup for the error trace logs as they gets word-wrapped and debugging the error becomes difficult.

Comment: Ok @DebanjanB, thanks for the heads up....

Comment: @DebanjanB, Exception block is corrected and pasted without ""blockquote"

Comment: @RGoyal I still don't see the actual exception which was raised which should have been at the top

Answer (score 2):

You above code looks buggy. You need to break the loop:

```
WebElement namesList = Hooks.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='names_department']//ul"));
List<WebElement> options = namesList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
    option.findElement(By.tagName("Span")).click();
    break;
}
//options.get(2).click();//throws exception
```

Or something like below.

```
WebElement namesList = Hooks.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='names_department']//ul"));
List<WebElement> options = namesList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
   if("Sirsa".equalsIgnoringCase(option.getText())){
      option.click(); 
      //option.findElement(By.tagName("Span")).click();
      break;
   }
 }
```

Above code at least not throw an exception of command timeout. And if you found the click doesn't take effect then you can use alternate of triggering click using javascript.

To deal with such cases one of the well know open source framework [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) provides feature called [custom component](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/custom_component.html). Using that you can have your custom implementation for webelement.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use JavascriptExecutor

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", options.get(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    List<WebElement> elements = 
    Hooks.driver.findElements(By.xpath("/*@id='names_department']//ul/li"));
    for (int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++) {
        if (elements.get(i).getTagName().equals("span") {
        elements.get(i).click()
        }       
    }
    elements.get(2).click();
```